# getting all the checked checkboxes in a form

Tags: jquery

i will get my form dynamically.

```
   var formid = $('#' + radio.id).closest('form').attr('id');
```

How do i find all the checkbox checked elements in the respective form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#' + radio.id).closest('form').find('input:checkbox:checked')
```

Answer (score 21):

Use single selector:

```
$("#formid input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    $(this) // do your staff with each checkbox
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox[name='type']:checked").each(function()
{
    // add $(this).val() to your array
});
```

Comment: He does not want to filter by name, besides that you need to quote the attr value (`[name="type"]`)

Comment: Thank you for correction. he wants get all the checked elements rit ? will this work ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost similar to [Javascript loop get name of checked checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31107397/5922263) but improving on @FosterZ answer, the item **$this.val()** may always simply have string **'on'**, so I have added the line which can grap the name also. It also loops on the entire form; just give the right form id.

```
let cbCheckedArray = [];
let currentVal = '';    //may always just be 'on'
let currentName = '';
$("#form-id input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    currentVal = $(this).val();
    currentName = $(this).attr("name");
    cbCheckedArray.push(currentName);
    alert('here: '+currentName);
});
```